# Are there any reasons why Heroku might silently reject requests with status code 400?

Tags: heroku

I'm trying to diagnose an issue whereby an embedded device running an HTTP client to issue requests to a Node.js Web application running on Heroku is receiving empty responses with status code 400.

The problem I'm facing is that the presumably failing requests do not even appear in the Heroku logs, so it's certainly not the Web application code returning those 400s.

On the other hand issuing requests to the Web application from a browser works just fine and the requests do appear in the Heroku logs.

I'm trying to figure out whether the embedded client is really sending requests at all and I'm wondering if there are any reasons why Heroku might send back those 400s without the requests even appearing in the logs.

Answer (score 1):

The cause was related to a badly implemented HTTP client in the device that was issuing requests omitting the *host* header.
Adding the header solved the problem.